# Implementing inherited method in parent class

Tags: python

I'm attempting to understand Python inheritence and below class `CarWithBrakes` inherits from class `Car` :

```
class Car :
    def __init__(self , wheels):
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.jsonTransform = {}
        self.jsonTransform['wheels'] = wheels
        
    def toJson(self):
        return self.jsonTransform
    
    def get_wheels(self):
        return self.wheels
    
class CarWithBrakes(Car):
    
    def __init__(self , car, brakes):
        self.car = car
        self.brakes = brakes

    def toJson(self):
        self.jsonTransform = {}
        self.jsonTransform['wheels'] = self.car.wheels
        self.jsonTransform['brakes'] = self.brakes
        return self.jsonTransform
    
c = Car("wheels")
print(c.toJson())

b = CarWithBrakes(c , "brakes")
print(b.toJson())
print(b.get_wheels())
```

Running this code produces:

```
{'wheels': 'wheels'}
{'wheels': 'wheels', 'brakes': 'brakes'}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-9b4b5598414b> in <module>
     30 b = CarWithBrakes(c , "brakes")
     31 print(b.toJson())
---> 32 print(b.get_wheels())

<ipython-input-62-9b4b5598414b> in get_wheels(self)
     11 
     12     def get_wheels(self):
---> 13         return self.wheels
     14 
     15 class CarWithBrakes(Car):
```

Shouldn't wheels attribute be available as `CarWithBrakes` inherits from `Car`?

Comment: Why is `CarWithBrakes`'s `__init__` accepting a `car`? It should take `wheels` and `break` and then call `super.__init__(wheels)` at the end. Remember inheritance is an _is a_ relationship not a _has a_ relationship. So you don't make a separate Car object and pass that to CarWithBrakes, CarWithBrakes doesn't _have_ a Car, it _is_ a Car.

Comment: Also note that in `CarWithBrakes`'s `toJson` you are repeating the code in the base `__init__`. Instead of that, in the inherited `__init__` after calling the `super()` constructor, simply update the dict by doing `self.jsonTransform['brakes'] = brakes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here.

`CarWithBrakes` does override the `__init__` method of `Car`. In the overridden method, the `wheels` attribute is not set. Usually, you delegate work you want to share with the child class (such as setting the `wheels` attribute) to the child class initializer via `super().__init__(...)`.

Second, you are unnecessarily mixing inheritance and aggregation. A `CarWithBrakes` *is-a* car by inheritance, there's no reason to pass a `Car` instance to hold onto in `CarWithBrakes.__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you will have to call the base constructor if you want that to execute for your derived type. You can do this using `super()` which allows you to access the base type.

So your `CarWithBrakes` should look like this:

```
class CarWithBrakes(Car):
    def __init__(self, wheels, brakes):
        # call base implementation
        super().__init__(wheels)        

        # no need to set `self.wheels` since that is done in the base
        # but do set the `brakes` which the base class does not know about
        self.brakes = brakes
```

You also don’t want to pass in a `car` instance but instead create a `CarWithBrakes` directly. A CarWithBrakes *is* a Car; but a CarWithBrakes does not contain another Car.